# Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: "'

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

```
$("#medicine").append('<tr class="hide1 newRow"   id="row'+medCurrentIndex+'">'
                +'<td>'+medtype[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
                +'<td>'+medicineName[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
                +'<td>'+frequency[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
                +'<td>'+dose[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
                +'<td>'+quantity[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
                +'<td>'+numberofDays[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
                +'<c:choose>'
                +'<c:when test="${role eq 'doctor' }">'
                +'<td><button class="btn" type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="editMedRow('+medCurrentIndex+');">Edit</button></td>'
                +'<td><button class="btn"  type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteMedRow('+medCurrentIndex+');">Delete</button></td>'
                +'</c:when>'
                +'<c:otherwise>'
                +'<td><input type="text" id="cost" /></td>'
                +'</c:otherwise>'
                +'</c:choose>'
                +'</tr>');
```

is this code legal to write in javaScript of ***JSP***?
because its giving me following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>
> #### Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for c in /WEB-INF/views/prescriptionTemporary.jsp
>
> 79: Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: "'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing jstl tags in javascript is not going to work. JQuery's `.append(...)` method is going to fire on the client side long after jstl tags are parsed.

If your goal is to choose, via jstl, what to append, a significant rewrite is needed.

---

edit:

Try this:

```
$("#medicine").append('<tr class="hide1 newRow"   id="row'+medCurrentIndex+'">'
   +'<td>'+medtype[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
   +'<td>'+medicineName[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
   +'<td>'+frequency[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
   +'<td>'+dose[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
   +'<td>'+quantity[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
   +'<td>'+numberofDays[medCurrentIndex]+'</td>'
       <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${role eq 'doctor' }">
           +'<td><button class="btn" type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="editMedRow('+medCurrentIndex+');">Edit</button></td>'
           +'<td><button class="btn"  type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteMedRow('+medCurrentIndex+');">Delete</button></td>'
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           +'<td><input type="text" id="cost" /></td>'
       </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>
   +'</tr>');
```

I want to emphasize that although the above snippet might work, **I wouldn't recommend it**. A better solution would be to dump `${role}` into a global variable or a hidden input and do the decision making from the JS side. Or set the whole append string in jstl. Mixing the two makes this significantly harder to read.

Comment: when i used <c:if> instead of <c:choose> it worked properly but when i try <c:choose> it throws exception.y?

Comment: As Luiggi pointed out, the jstl parser will find illegal chars between choose and when. Namely two single quotes and a plus sign.

Comment: Ya tried this and it worked but some time worked and some time not

Answer (score 2):

Any Java code inside JSP will be evaluated at render time. This means, the server will read the JSP code and will start replacing any scriptlet or custom tag (like JSTL) for the necessary Java code. This can be easily explained by this example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = '${x}';
</script>
```

Or in JSTL form:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = '<c:out value="${x}" />';
</script>
```

Assuming `x` is a request attribute with a value of "Hello World", this will generate this output in HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 'Hello World';
</script>
```

In your case, it will try to convert this part of the code to its JSTL form:

```html
<c:choose>'
    <!--  ^ this character is invalid. There must be a <c:when> right after <c:choose>
            v this character is also invalid. There must be a <c:when> right after <c:choose> -->
            +'<c:when test="${role eq 'doctor' }">'
```

In short, you should not try to append any kind of Java code (scriptlet, expression language, custom tags like JSTL, etc) from JavaScript.

Comment: what's  alternate solution for this?

Comment: @user2696142 first you have to understand the explanation in the answer. After that you'll come up with a solution. One possibility is to move the JSTL logic to JavaScript side and choose what to append and what not, by simulating the logic in your `<c:choose>` tag.